# Type hint for Callable that takes kwargs

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

I want to do something like

```
from typing import Callable


def a(foo: Callable[[int], None]):
    foo(b=5)
```

This code works, but gives a warning `Unexpected argument`.

Defining as

```
def a(foo: Callable[[int], None]):
    foo(5)
```

works with no warnings as expected.

---

**How can I pass in an expected argument as a `kwarg` into a function with the type checker not being angry at me?**

Comment: That's more an issue with `mypy` (or whatever tool is giving you the warning) than an issue with type hinting.

Comment: Think of a type hint as a mathematical property of a function, not something that reflects the semantics of a particular implementation of functions in Python. `foo` takes an integer argument; whether you *provide* the argument as a positional argument or a keywords argument is immaterial to static type-checking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Callable` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) say

> There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types.

However they also say

> `Callable[..., ReturnType]` (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments and returning `ReturnType`

Applying here, that would be

```
def a(foo: Callable[..., None]):
```

You will lose the `int` annotation, but it's either that, living with the warning or explicitly surpassing it.

Comment: I don’t get why this is the accepted answer, the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68474456/735926) requires three lines of code but is more type-safe.

Answer (score 16):

You can use a "callable protocol" here, so:

```
import typing

class MyCallableType(typing.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, bar:int) -> None:
        ...

def a(foo: MyCallableType):
    foo(32)
    foo(bar=32)
```

Now, testing the above with `mypy`:

```
jarrivillaga$ mypy --version
mypy 0.910
jarrivillaga$ mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Note, this allows mypy to catch all kinds of errors, e.g. a function with the wrong argument name, or if we want `b` to be a function that specifies a keyword-only bar argument:

```
import typing

class MyCallableType(typing.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, b:int) -> None:
        ...

def a(foo: MyCallableType):
    foo(32)
    foo(b=32)

def bar(b: int) -> None:
    pass

def baz(*, b: int) -> None:
    pass

def bing(x: int) -> None:
    pass

a(bar)
a(baz)
a(bing)
```

And mypy will complain with the following:

```
jarrivillaga$ mypy test.py
test.py:21: error: Argument 1 to "a" has incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'b')], None]"; expected "MyCallableType"
test.py:22: error: Argument 1 to "a" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], None]"; expected "MyCallableType"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, but defining a new type is way too much in my opinion for just a function that takes int, which is why I opt for the `...` solution.

Comment: Can you explain *why* the need to define a new type? After all, no new static information is added by that.

Comment: @Gulzar simply because `Callable` does not support any way to indicate the names of the arguments or that they are keyword arguments. I think `mypy` was working on extensions that would have allowed it, but they were abandoned and the new guidance is just to use a callable protocol.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve this is to use 3.10+ `typing.Concatenate`:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Concatenate

# expects extraction dir as its first param and leave the door open for kwargs
ExtractionCallback = Callable[Concatenate[Path, ...], None]

# expects extraction dir, processing dir and kwargs
TransformationCallback = Callable[Concatenate[Path, Path, ...], None]
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate

Comment: @Gulzar this should be the accepted answer, does exactly what was asked in a straightforward way.

Comment: <3.10 it's available via `typing_extensions`.